# Who wants a hat? Come and get your hats!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

'Tis the season! [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) is back on participating Stack Exchange sites in full effect, from **15 December 2014** until **4 January 2015**.

For those of us who haven't seen it on other SE sites, as this would be the first for Expats.SE, Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can "wear":

[image]

Sites vote explicitly to participate, and if the idea is welcomed by site's users, it will be enabled in the aforementioned period. It's important to know that even if Winter Bash is enabled, users can explicitly opt out if they want to (there will be "I hate hats" option on their profile page which will revert the site to its familiar look for the user).

So, it's time to decide if we want hats on our Expats.SE! **Vote** on the answers below **until 30 November 2014**. We'll enable hats only if there's sufficient support for it (for some yet undetermined value of "sufficient"). Please don't downvote an option, rather upvote only the one you choose. Of course, comment as necessary.

Your mod friends at Expats.SE remind you to enjoy hats responsibly.

Comment: While I voted yes, I imagine that there's got to be *someone* who wants to vote no but doesn't have the rep for it. ;)

Comment: @lswank I am not sure somebody without less than 15 rep has earned the right to decide if we wear hats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### YES!

Bring on the hats, can't ever get enough hats.

Comment: wow such fun, much hats!

Answer (score 1):

### No!

I'm a firm believer in bare heads.